# Crash when maximizing Thunderbird on 13.10

Tags: unity, thunderbird, unity-tweak-tool

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, I've installed Unity tweak tool.
Sometimes, when I maximize a window, the system freeze and I can't do anything (the system is still in freeze after 3 hours). I have to reboot my pc.

The last example was yesterday, when I've maximized Thunderbird by sliding the window to the top of my screen.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using dual screen.
I've tried to find an error in

```
/var/log/syslog
```

but I didn't find anything... Is there the right place to look ?
Tell me if I need to add any info, I will be happy to do so !

EDIT 1:

To find error in syslog, I've done :

```
less /var/log/syslog.1 | grep error
```

I've also looked manually trough the last entries...

EDIT 2:

After playing a bit with multiples softwares, it looks like the crash only appears when using Thunderbird ! Have you had similar experience with Thunderbird ?

EDIT 3:

I should have say it from the beginning, but it only happens when I resize a windows by pulling it on the edge of the screen !

Comment: I've experienced the same with Google Chrome. It only happens for me when resizing a window by moving the title bar to the top or one of the sides of the screen. The scree freezes during the animation and the mouse cursor still shows the gripping hand icon.

Comment: Yes, same for me ! I should have say that in my question ! (I edit it). It may be related to the graphic card driver ! Did you solve the issue yet ?

Comment: No, it just happened yesterday. Never had it before. My graphics card is a newish AMD.

Comment: Mine is "old" Nvidia

Comment: BUG: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1244754 Will be fixed sooner or later.

Comment: Thx for the information ! I will follow this bug !

Comment: @Laurent - are you confirming that this is actually your bug?  If so this question should be closed and the bounty returned to the OP.

Comment: I have this constantly happening to me with eclipse (installed from repositories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Its a Bug, here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1244754
It will be soon fixed in Ubuntu 14.04. So, You must use Evolution instead of Thunderbird.

**To install Evolution mail** press the SuperKey and type: software center.

When the software center is open follow these steps:

In the search field type: evolution mail
Select the search result
Click on the More Info button
Mark the plugins you want to install
Click on the Install button
Enter your password
Click on the Authenticate button

When Evolution mail is installed you can close the software center. To start Evoilution       mail press the SuperKey and type: evolution.

Comment: Or just using the maximize button instead of pulling edges, as it seems it's the only time it's crashing for him.

Comment: I do not think that advising someone to change to another different mail agent is a good things. Evolution and Thunderbird are very different beasts...